# What does the backslash in Pari mean?

Tags: pari, pari-gp

What does the backslash in Pari mean? As in: `a(n) = 1 + n\4`

It it very hard to find an answer using traditional search engines, because the terms "pari" and "backslash" appear in various independent contexts.

Comment: Hi! \ is integer division operator. Traditional division outputs the integer and fractional parts. \ will output only the integer part skipping the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "traditional search engines", use Pari's online help: `?? \`

```
   The  expression x \y is the Euclidean quotient of x and y.   If y is a real
scalar, this is defined as floor(x/y) if y > 0, and ceil(x/y) if y < 0 and the
division  is  not  exact.    Hence the remainder x -  (x\y)*y is in [0,  |y|[.

   Note that when y is an integer and x a polynomial, y is first promoted to a
polynomial of degree 0.  When x is a vector or matrix, the operator is applied
componentwise.
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting so late. I am not using PARI myself, just found someone else's code. Thanks